# UIRefreshControl stucks only in iPhone X/ iPhone XR

Tags: ios, xcode, uirefreshcontrol

I am working on an application where I implement UIRefreshControl. All things going fine but when testing move on iPhone X or iPhone XR, pthen a weird problem raised.

***The problem is UIRefreshControl Stucks sometimes when we try to refersh the list. Or we can say it occurring 1 out of 10 cases, If we uses it continuously. This issue is only generating in iPhone X or XR. In other device everything works fine.***

If we talk about the code, I used the code which works perfectly. Here is a code snippet for UIRefreshControl.

Initialization:

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl? = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:#selector(refreshAssignmentData(_:)),  for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl.tintColor = CustomColors.themeColorGreen
    return refreshControl
}()
```

I call this func in API, so when I get response it will add.

```
 func addRefreshControl() {
    /// Here adding refresh control
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.tblView?.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
    } else {
        self.tblView?.addSubview(self.refreshControl!)
    }
    refreshControl?.alpha = 1
 }
```

And when we use pull to refresh this method calls

```
@objc func refreshAssignmentData(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.performSelector(inBackground: #selector(self.getNewAssignmentListInBackground(_:)), with: nil)
    }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.arrAllAssignment?.removeAll()
            self.arrAllAssignment = [AssignmentModel]()
            self.intPage = 1
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        }
}
```

All these lines of code working fine in other device range except iPhone X series.

Any suggestion please...

Comment: Your code seems accurate. One thing that you can try is while ending refresh use this:

  `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.tblView?.refreshControl. endRefreshing()
    } else {
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }`

Comment: Hi...Thanks for suggestion...I will try it...